# wpa_supplicant.conf Changes Disappear

Tags: raspbian, wireless

I'm trying to setup my wireless on a raspberry pi 4 running raspbian, and I'm making changes to the wpa_supplicant.conf file per other answers here on Stack Exchange.  However, after I make the changes to the file and reboot or turn wireless off/on, the changes I made to the file disappear.  Why aren't my changes persistent?

I did confirm that the changes were written to the file after exiting nano using more on the file.

Comment: Is there another wpa_supplicant.conf on /boot? That gets copied in under some circumstances, replacing the one in /etc/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what WiFi configuration do you use but **wpa_supplicant** has the ability to configure itself and find some necessary options. It will store these settings for next use in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, the one that you try to edit. This is what the option

```
update_config=1
```

allows. Set it to `update_config=0` and **wpa_supplicant** will never change its configuration.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you for taking the time to comment on my issue.

Comment: @Ingo well I have the same problem , but even when I change "update_config=1"
to "update_config=0" , it still reverts back to what it was before , even the "update_config=0" is changed back to "update_config=1".

Comment: @Hitman2847 Do you find some modifications in wpa_supplicant.conf?

Comment: @Ingo yes but only the ones system made

Answer (score 2):

I've a doubt in your question here. Only changes are disappeared or the whole content gets disappeared? If the whole content is disappeared, it is a common problem which might be solved by setting the wifi-country and region correctly or by setting following things correctly:

```
country=us
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
 scan_ssid=1
 ssid="MyNetworkSSID"
 psk="Pa55w0rd1234"
}
```

Here change the `US` with 2 letters of your country code. 
This might help.

Comment: The first three lines were originally in the file (with the correct country code), and they remain after my addition for the network disappears after reboot or toggling wifi off/on. I’ve “solved” the problem by changing my router to broadcast the SSID and connecting via the GUI.